# How to Set/Calculate pole angle of IK constraint so the chain does not move?

Tags: rigging, bones

How to calculate the exact pole angle so when I add Pole bone the IK chain does not move?

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is what the `pole angle` is:

[image]

Its a signed angle between the Base_Bone's X axis and the projected Pole_axis onto Base_Bone's XZ plane. The direction of projection is IK_axis.

Fill in the bone names, it will print the appropriate pole angle into System console. Then you can set the IK constraint with that Pole bone and angle and the IK chain won't move:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *

def signed_angle(vector_u, vector_v, normal):
    # Normal specifies orientation
    angle = vector_u.angle(vector_v)
    if vector_u.cross(vector_v).angle(normal) < 1:
        angle = -angle
    return angle

def get_pole_angle(base_bone, ik_bone, pole_location):
    pole_normal = (ik_bone.tail - base_bone.head).cross(pole_location - base_bone.head)
    projected_pole_axis = pole_normal.cross(base_bone.tail - base_bone.head)
    return signed_angle(base_bone.x_axis, projected_pole_axis, base_bone.tail - base_bone.head)

base_bone = bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones["BASE_BONE_NAME"]
ik_bone = bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones["IK_BONE_NAME"]
pole_bone = bpy.context.active_object.pose.bones["POLE_BONE_NAME"]

pole_angle_in_radians = get_pole_angle(base_bone,
                                       ik_bone,
                                       pole_bone.matrix.translation)
pole_angle_in_deg = round(180*pole_angle_in_radians/3.141592, 3)
print(pole_angle_in_deg)
```

Comment: I have new respect for Maya. Its pole vector is flawless. I haven't given up in Blender though. I'll see if I can find a workaround

Comment: @allen I agree, Maya's rigging is much much superior than this. Except for advanced IK  and some bone dependency cycles all can be replicated in blender though. But it's not that easy.

Comment: Its extremely frustrating. I've spent a lot of time making quality rigs for Maya and I love fancy rigs. I was able to find enough great tutorials to create "Driven Keys" in Blender, foot roll and banking, ect. I wasn't far off from duplicating a production quality Maya rig in Blender. But the accuracy with respect to the bind pose is terrible! It's a shame since I love to rig.

Comment: Very useful information, no matter how old the post. Just bookmarked the page. Thank you.

Comment: for some reason the angle generated by this script didn't work for me, but it was still useful, I adjusted the pole angle manually and used the script to calculate how far it currently is from the perfect angle :)