# Change pole angle without affecting mesh

Tags: mesh, rigging

I have rigged a zombie, and when I change the pole angle it affects the mesh's flow. I have tried applying the armature both before and after changing the poles, but nothing works. Examples:

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to change the pole angle without affecting the mesh?

Comment: You mean the transform axis?

Comment: You can always remove weights for that bone, rotate, and re- paint. However I think with a .blend file it would be pretty easy to come up with a better solution.

Comment: You have IK's. That might be messing stuff up. Try it without, then see if there's a way to do it with.

Comment: The pole angle influences the IK chain and correspond to the pole bone position. They need to be in sync. To calculate the proper angle for your bone see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19754/how-to-set-calculate-pole-angle-of-ik-constraint-so-the-chain-does-not-move. To calculate the bone position for your specific angle it is the same but reversed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the pole angle is messing the mesh up due to an IK Constraint. Disable the constraint, change the bone roll instead of pole angle, then re-enable and adjust pole angle to correct.

Answer (score -1):

Before you apply armature you have to apply the adjusted pose as the rest pose. Select Armature and hit CTRL+A.