# How to IK rig legs

Tags: animation, armature, bones, constraints, inverse-kinematics

I have a simple character. I would like rig the legs so that I can easily control them. How can I IK rig my characters leg?

[image]

[**.blend file**](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33524)

Comment: Do you need reverse foot or just the simpliest IK?

Comment: If the foot would stay level, that would be best.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First you will need a **target bone** for the Ik - for example a copy of the foot bone. Make sure this bone is not parented to anything (except when you have a root/master bone - then parent it to root/master)

[image]

Now in pose mode add an **IK constraint** to the shin bone and setup it like in the picture. You can do this fast by selecting the *target_bone* first (copy of *foot_bone*), then the *shin_bone* and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>I</kbd>. Set the IK chain length to 2.

[image]

Last step is to add **Copy Rotation constraint** to *foot_bone*. 
Select *target_bone* (copy of *foot_bone*), select *foot_bone*,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd>

[image]

Now your leg is controlled with the *target bone*. You can also add a **Pole bone** for the IK constraint so the direction of the knee is defined:

[image]

You can eyeball the *pole_angle*, how to set it precisely is explained here: [How to Set/Calculate pole angle of IK constraint so the chain does not move?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19754/how-to-set-calculate-pole-angle-of-ik-constraint-so-the-chain-does-not-move/19755#19755)

Comment: is _foot_bone_ the original or the copy?

Comment: original - the copy is target_bone, i will edit it so its clear.

Comment: In the Copy Rotations constraint I can't add the new bone as the vertex group. Why is this?

Comment: Make sure characters armature object is in *Target:* input field and not some mesh object

Comment: Also if your leg doesn't bend correctly (remains stiff even if you move the target). Make sure to go to edit mode and give a small rotation forward to the shin bone. this will make the IK constraint work properly (kudos: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/203683/83141)