# How to make a clothing mesh follow an arm mesh?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones

I'm trying to model, rig and animate simple FPS hands (hands only, no body). I have the guns all set up and animated and I just have to do these hands.

I've rigged it and edited the weights a bit, but when I move the bones in the arm, the arm itself moves perfectly fine but the "clothing" I've put on them doesn't follow the arm right, it rotates slower than the arm and falls behind, and also scales smaller as the arm moves.

[image]
[image]
[image]

How do I solve this? Thanks

Blend file included https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3g6-EZ98ikrS2c0am42VTNwYjg

Comment: Please don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To solve this:

- Select your mesh and switch to edit mode
- Select all using <kbd>A</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>P</kbd> then choose `By loose parts`
- Now there will be two meshes, the arm and the cloth. Select the cloth mesh and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> then `clear Parent`
- Select your cloth mesh then select the armature as well using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ Right Click
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select `with Automatic weighting`

and this will be the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks that worked out fine! I'm guessing the next part to work out is Inverse Kinetics or something like that?

Comment: @BrianTien please accept and upvote the answer if it solved your problem. For IK check this http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21385/2517 or ask another question.