# objects joined but dont move together

Tags: rigging

[image: objects dont move together but they are joined]

1. I created a body and some clothing (just objects shaped into clothing) and I joined them together. I then created armatures and joined with automatic weights to the body. problem is the mesh does not move with the clothing

Comment: Try this piece of advice from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77640/how-to-make-a-clothing-mesh-follow-an-arm-mesh Also, make sure you update the Blender version if you can, the 2.82 is better on many levels. I hope it helps!

Comment: Did you add the clothing after binding to the mesh? May need to rebind.