# rig problem: knees bend sideways instead of forward and backward

Tags: animation, rigging

The knees bend sideways instead of forward and backward(normal) I tried:
"Recalculate Roll > View Axis" but that didn't do anything. How to fix it?

I'm not sure how to embed the GIF:

[Imgur](https://i.imgur.com/RnafzSD.gifv)

Comment: Thanks for the help, the problem was with the pole angle. I set one to 0 and the other to 180 and somehow for some reason, it worked properly.

Comment: You are welcome. Answer posted if you can tick and mark it as solved to help future users facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the IK Pole Target and pole angle. Follow JerryNo's answers [How to IK rig legs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21385/2517) and [How to Set/Calculate pole angle of IK constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19755/2517)