# IK constraint rotates the wrong direction

Tags: rigging

As can be seen in the picture below ~~
[image]

What should I do to fix this? ~~
Tried setting Pole Target. The angle got right but the mesh looks wrong when deformed
[image]
blend file:
[image]

Comment: You need to set the IK Pole Target and pole angle. Follow JerryNo's answers [How to IK rig legs](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21385/2517) and [How to Set/Calculate pole angle of IK constraint](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19755/2517)

Comment: Tried that. The angle got right but the mesh is impropriately deformed :(

Comment: please updated your question with your attempt and show what happens.

Comment: just set the pole target as: mixamorig:LeftLefCtrl and you're ready to go

Comment: Above, I've added an image of what happened when I set the Pole Target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few issues:

- In Edit Mode, select mixamorig:LeftUpLeg. Under Bone:Transform uncheck lock, or the rest won't work.
- In Edit Mode, select the root of mixamorig:LeftUpLeg and the tail of mixamorig:LeftLeg. Shift+S, Cursor to Selected.  This will place the cursor directly between the two.  Select the root of mixamorig:LeftLeg (the "knee") and Shift+S Selected to Cursor.  This will snap it right to the middle. From the right view, move it a bit forwards.  Part of your issue is that you have the initial position with the knee bending inside.  Having a slight bend forwards will help the IK solve correctly.

[image: Leg Position Fix]

- Select mixamorig:LeftUpLeg and mixamorig:LeftLeg. In Edit Mode, hit Control+N and recalculate the roll angles to "Global X Axis."  This'll align the Z to the X axis, keeping the bone X axis facing forwards.
- In Edit Mode, select the whole bone mixamorig:LeftLegCtrl. With the cursor still at the knee, Shift+S Snap Selected to Cursor. The pole vector bone will snap its base to the knee.  Move it forwards a ways from the right view.
- Assign the pole vector object to the IK contstraint on mixamorig:LeftLeg.

Once that's all done the IK should work fine.
[image: Working Leg]