# Inverse Kinematics to rig a Truck with a Trailer

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to animate a truck with a trailer on it can follow a path realistically. I know I should be rigging the model using inverse kinematics but I can't get it to work.

I found a previous post on this topic but I can't replicate the answer that u/DrJamgo gave. Would someone be able to walk me through this or just share a .blend file where they got it to work? I don't mean to seem lazy I've just had no luck on this after working on it for hours.

[image]

[Does anyone know how to rig a truck/trailer so that the trailer follows the truck in a realistic way?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81872/does-anyone-know-how-to-rig-a-truck-trailer-so-that-the-trailer-follows-the-truc)

Comment: yes, he doesn't give any explanation at all   :/

Comment: I know he does explain it but I still can't get it to work. One thing I'm confused about is the direction of the bones in the gif are going the opposite direction from the bones shown in the example "how to rig ik legs" post that was linked. So I don't know what other relationships need to be reversed

Comment: If you understood the bone organization could you please edit your answer and explain in detail his method? I guess it will make easier for someone to help

Comment: I'm not sure if I do understand their method since I can't get it to work. I did link to their explanation which would be better than my attempt anyway

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the following blend file:
https://nofile.io/f/xHeoevF0kwr/car10xxx.blend