# How to make a bone pull other bones dynamically?

Tags: rigging, bones

So, I'm relatively new to blender, And I've been working on a steam train with carriages for the last couple of days.

I wanted to rig the train so that, when I pull on an IK bone, the train will follow it dynamically, like a snake.

Here are some screenshots to illustrate my issue:

[image: This is the train model. All the carriages are separate objects.]
This is the train model. All the carriages are separate objects.

[image: This is the model with the rig.]
This is the model with the rig.

[image: And this is what happens when I try to add IK bones. Everything just goes crazy.]
And this is what happens when I try to add IK bones. Everything just goes crazy.

Would appreciate some help with this issue.

Sorry if I used the wrong terminology.

Comment: are you sure you want to use this technique to make your train move? Because if you want it to follow a curve, the other bones won't follow correctly. Batfinger proposed a solution for this kind of case here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/133012/line-of-bones-to-travel-and-conform-to-curve-like-train-on-a-track-snake/133032

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81872/does-anyone-know-how-to-rig-a-truck-trailer-so-that-the-trailer-follows-the-truc