# Rigging IK moves whole leg CRAZY

Tags: rigging, bones, makehuman

I have a problem about my IK bone on the feet. It **moves** the leg as it suppose to move, but the movement isn't smooth and by one drag(I press G) it goes crazy as in pictures. What can I do for fixing it? [image]

[image]

Comment: Something is not right with your setup, it is hard to say what without having the file. Probably some bone parenting issue. You can see this to compare what you did differently: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21379/how-to-ik-rig-legs/21385#21385