# Need help with bone constraints for creating joints

Tags: armature, bones, constraints, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I have this rig that has an arm composed of 3 bones. I have an IK bone set up already to control the entire chain. I would like to use the Elbow.L bone to create a pole target that acts as a joint, however everything I've tried so far either locks all bones in place or does nothing at all. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

[image: Visual]

Comment: check this, elbow is the same as knee: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21385/7777

Comment: see I did that and I'm not getting the desired result. I'm not sure what it is I am doing wrong since I am following it step by step.