# Legs twists after adding a pole target to IK

Tags: rigging

I just got finished adding IK to the leg bones of my model, but when I add a pole target the leg twists immediately,
I tried fixing this by rotating the pole angle but this results in the IK not following the pole target as it should, 
I checked the axes of the bones to make sure everything was in order, and I could not find anything wrong
what should I do?

The following img shows the before and after of attaching the pole target
[image]

.blend download : [image]

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny I've already seen that post, it does not answer my question, unfortunately 
I've found the correct pole angle (-79.628) to prevent the mesh from twisting, but then the IK chain does not follow to pole target correctly...

Comment: Then probably something else is broken, have a look at also this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21379/how-to-ik-rig-legs maybe that could help. I can't look into your .blend now but later I will check what could be the problem..

Comment: I checked the link, it didn't help... but I do appreciate you looking at my .blend

Comment: The leg bone chain is straight, if you pre-bend the knee in edit mode (just a little bit), the IK solver starts behaving predictably again.

Comment: I didn't quite understand...?

Comment: Move the knee joint so the legs are bend a little bit. In edit mode. The problem is the legs are straight.