# RIGGING in 2.79b ~ IK handles cause hands/feet to detatch from the body, alternatives? (Foot rigging)

Tags: rigging, armature, parent, inverse-kinematics

I've followed a couple of tutorials to learn how to rig my flying humanoid character.
Both of them tell me to unparent feet/hands bones and parent them to added bones that will work as IK handles.

GOOD: this allows me to rotate feet/hands freely while also driving legs/arms IK chains.

BAD: whenever I move the IK handles beyond legs/arms' maximum extension, the feet/hands' bones and mesh follow the IK handle resulting in a stretched mesh.
(See screenshot from one of the aforementioned tutorials)
[image]

This is unacceptable.

Alternatives?

Comment: Please see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21379/how-to-ik-rig-legs

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny
It works, thank you! ^.^
I'll vote your answer in that page, pity I cant give it points for being the best one. ^^

Answer (score -1):

Parent the foot to the IK controller (therefore now it's unparented from the lowerleg, as explained in your tutorials).

[image]

Give your lowerleg a *IK* constraint with the controller as *Target*:

[image]

Now to make sure that the foot sticks to the lowerleg, give the foot a *Copy Location* constraint, with the lowerleg as *Target*, a *Head/Tail* value of 1, and a *Space* setting > *World Space* / *World Space*.

[image]

file here: [image]

Comment: It works!! ^O^
But why "world space/world space"? Not that I have any alternative or reason to reject this setting, I just wanna fully understand what you made me do. ^.^

Comment: This makes a dependency cycle..

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny
Please, elaborate.... -.-'

Comment: The lowerleg depends on the target through IK constraint, the target depends on the lowerleg through Copy location constraint. The rig does not update correctly because of this.

Comment: @JaroslavJerrynoNovotny
I cant confirm through practice, now, but I trust your word, AND your link did the trick, thank you! ^^

Comment: @moonboots
Sorry, Jaroslav's comment/answer better fits my needs and my crave for correctness. ^^'

Comment: mmh why did someone downvote my answer? did I give a bad answer? not sure to understand...

Comment: @Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny, actually I don't give the Copy Location to the IK controller but to the foot, so I guess you misunderstood my answer  ;)

Comment: @moonboots but the foot depends on the IK controller bone through parent, so it's the same. You can see the dependency cycle being print out in the console.

Comment: the foot is parented to the controller, the foot is attached to the lowerleg with the constraint, and of course the lowerleg is controlled by the controller, doesn't seem to be any dependency or bug, I've edited my answer, please check the file