# Control Bone Has No Fixed Position

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

[image: rig]
I have this rig set up with a IK constraint that has one bone that acts as the control for the leg armature (Labeled in Screenshot).  I have been following a tutorial, and it shows me how to rig it, but apparently I am missing something.  When My control bone moves far enough away from the IK bone, it will "migrate" away from the bones - see the picture.  Is this supposed to happen?  What must I do to make this work correctly?

Comment: I think it is what's supposed to happen with this kind of rigging as the controller is supposed to be independent from the leg and foot, and I guess the foot should be parented to the controller so that when you rotate the controller, the foot follows, but maybe link the tutorial?

Comment: It's a course that you had to pay for on Udemy.

Comment: here was a similar question, maybe it will help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132366/rigging-in-2-79b-ik-handles-cause-hands-feet-to-detatch-from-the-body-alterna/132368#132368

Comment: Interesting... He posted a .blend file that I looked at.  It does the exact same thing.  Maybe that's the way it's supposed to be.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Jaroslav has linked to this other question that may help as well: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21379/how-to-ik-rig-legs