# Inverse Kinematics leg/arm rig bending the wrong way

Tags: rigging, rigify

I have a character who is rigged using 'Rigify'. I've put inverse kinematics on his two forearms and his two shins, and this problem is mainly a problem on his shins. I want his legs to be able to bend **only** like following:
[image]

But it can also bend this way, which I want to make impossible.

[image]

So basically - is there a way for an inverse kinematics rig to allow only bending in a certain direction?

Comment: You didn't generate the Rigify rig.. you only used the guide rig. Select the Guide rig and in Armature tab under Rigify hit Generate. Now you will get a rigify rig.

Answer (score 1):

I am 4 years too late, but still.
You need to create another bone outside the leg and it should not be parented to any other. Now open the bone constraints(where you created the inverse kinematics) and you will see "Pole Target", select your Armature and below will appear "Bone" and select the bone you created.
After that the bones will only bend in the direction of this pole target bone, so you should put it in front of the model.

Answer (score -2):

You must also create inverse kinematics for your upper leg and upper arms, the chain length for your lower legs and arms should be 2 and the chain length for your upper arm and legs should be one. The follow blog will be very helpful!

http://blog.digitaltutors.com/how-to-create-your-first-character-rig-in-blender-part-1/

Comment: That tutorial is wrong on so many levels. I advise not to rig like that - 2 IK constrains in arm or leg cause incorrect rotations, the correct way is to use PoleTargets. Also the constraints targets setup in that rig brings more work for an animator that could be avoided.

Comment: @Jerryno Wow how exactly do you set up 'Poletargets' because i began getting annoyed with the few errows from two IK when i was animating. Are there any tutorials you can refer me to? if so that would be great!

Comment: There is this for pole targets: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/19755/7777. BlenderCookie.com has some nice rigging tutorials. You can also reverse-engineer the rigify rig. That's about all I can recommend, sadly there ere not enough good resources out there about rigging.