# IK Rig (Pole Target Issue)

Tags: animation, inverse-kinematics

Hello there so i have a mesh with IK set up for the arm however as soon as i add a pole target and go back to Position moving for the IK Arm It Screws up the Mesh this only occurs after adding the pole target it works fine without it. Here's a video so you guys can see exactly what's going on http://puu.sh/tCZCS/3039f37ae6.mp4 Right Click Save as Mp4

Notice how in the beginning the IK works fine and after the pole target is added it just screws it up why this happen i need to understand what i did wrong also can you add more then 1 pole target in blender?

My main goal is to just have smooth rotations kinda like how IK does it with positioning it doesn't support Rotation Since IK only works for positioning

Comment: have a look at this: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19754/how-to-set-calculate-pole-angle-of-ik-constraint-so-the-chain-does-not-move/19755. Your question is probably a duplicate, but am not sure.

Comment: I'm a bit confused reading that other link. Basically what's happening is that the IK works fine without pole target as soon as the pole target is added it ruins the IK positioning and this occurs ONLY after adding the pole target i don't see how it ruins the chains as you can see in the video anything else i should do in order to prevent this?

Comment: No, it does not ruin it. Pole target purpose is to influence the direction to where the IK chain is pointing. Without it the IK chain points in *"some"* direction, but when you add it, it points in the *"defined"* direction. To make the *"some"* direction be the same as the *"defined"* direction in rest pose you need to calculate proper pole target angle or engineer the bone chain such it does not move in first place (by aligning it on local X axis for example).

Comment: that video was kinda bad since i added the pole target near the hand rather then near the elbow where it should be. Here's another video of the pole target being in the correct place but yet the same issue still occurs http://puu.sh/tUcNL/30eaaaa60b.mp4 any explanation as to why this happens despite the pole target being a proper position unless the elbow is also not the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out using a curve is not a good idea i managed to get it working by using bones only as the pole target and still keeping the chain in shape without distorting like how it was before.