# How to move pole target without moving child?

Tags: bones

I've been trying to move the elbow without moving the lower arm that it is connected to. I had to move it this far off to get the chain back to the starting position before I gave it the pole arm and it rotated.

Help?[image]

Comment: You need to move it only in plane defined by 3 points of the pole, shoulder and the wrist - more on this here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19754/how-to-set-calculate-pole-angle-of-ik-constraint-so-the-chain-does-not-move

Comment: I have seen that answer, but didn't quite understand it. I was hoping for another solution or explanation.