# Fixing my model's elbow bending inward

Tags: bones, rigify

So, I am using rigify for my humanoid model and I notice that when I move my arm by the hand, the elbow will generally bend in towards the torso, instead of out.

So it looks like this:

[image]

But I'd expect it to look like this:

[image]

Right now I have to manually adjust the arm to look correct, but I imagine that won't work out if I need to have the hand move via code, rather than a fixed animation. Below are some images of the metarig as it is lined up with the model:

[image]
[image]

I'm quite new to Blender and have made quite a few animations already. How can I fix the way the elbow bends with rigify, and will I need to completely re-do all the animations if I fix the bend?

edit of "Toggle Pole" turned on
[image]

Comment: Since your rig appears to have a complete set of bones and IK, does it also have "pole targets"?  Pole Targets are often used in conjunction with IK bones, for example using the Elbow PT so that the arm does not look contorted.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19754/how-to-set-calculate-pole-angle-of-ik-constraint-so-the-chain-does-not-move/19755  and https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/tracking/ik_solver.html

Comment: @james_t thanks a lot! turned on the toggle and that is looking a lot better. I never knew that existed. I'm importing a lot of this to unity, so I'm wondering what dictates how much of this is active in there. (also, If you want to write your answer as a full post I'll mark it as answering the question)

Comment: I'm learning also.  As you'll see for every answer I supply I have a question to ask!  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235168/why-are-rigifys-ik-pole-targets-hidden-in-pose-mode

Comment: To add to @James_t answer, there's a good video from Blender about arm rigging including pole targets [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S-2v_CKmVE8).

Comment: That video is a nice explanation of IK and pole targets, thank you. It makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your rig appears to have a complete set of bones and IK, does it also have "pole targets"? Pole Targets are often used in conjunction with IK bones, for example using the Elbow PT so that the arm does not look contorted.

refs:
[set pole](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19754/how-to-set-calculate-pole-angle-of-ik-constraint-so-the-chain-does-not-move/19755)

[IK Solver in ref manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/constraints/tracking/ik_solver.html)