# What vectors does the IK constraint align when using a Pole Target?

Tags: inverse-kinematics

For a research project, I need to reimplement Blender's constraints with behaviour as close as possible to their Blender implementation. I am currently struggling to understand how the inverse kinematics (IK) constraint uses the pole target in its computation. I see it has something to do with the x axis of the first bone of the chain, `chain[0]` (let's say that `chain` is a list of bones starting from the first one all the way to the effector, which is the one which bears the IK constraint)

I understand the effect of the pole angle (it applies after the IK solve, and simply rotates the first bone of the chain around the `(chain[-1].tail - chain[0].head)` axis). So for the sake of simplicity we can only discuss the case where that pole angle is 0.

According to [this stackexchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19754/how-to-set-calculate-pole-angle-of-ik-constraint-so-the-chain-does-not-move/19755), the IK constraint (with a pole angle of 0) supposedly aligns `pole_target.head - chain[0].head` (projected on the XZ plane of `chain[0]`) and `chain[0]`'s x axis. However, when I try to compute those vectors, they turn out not to be aligned.

So my question is : does anyone have any idea which vectors are aligned by the IK constraint?

Thanks!